# Is it possible to convert foreach operation into LINQ if it does two things?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have the **working** foreach as follows.

```
List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>();
foreach (Original original in originals)
  things.Add(new Thing(orignal));
```

Then, I got smart and LINQified it into the following, **still working** code.

```
IEnumerable<Thing> things = originals.Select(origo => new Thing(origo));
```

Feeling really proud of decimating the number of lines as well and LINQing myself to more clear code I realized that there's also the requirement to update the process table. It's imperative that the update occurs simultanously as we proceed through the transformation. So, with my tail between my legs and feels much less pride, I went back to the original code and added the notification method.

```
List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>();
foreach (Original original in originals)
{
  things.Add(new Thing(orignal));
  DoTell();
}
```

My question is if it's possible to keep the LINQie syntax and still be able to incorporate the teller somehow. I'm not hopeful that the code will look nice nor be more readable that way (although, it'd be awesome if it was). However, now it's a matter of academic curiosity and pure stubborness - I'd like to know if it **can** be done **at all**.

Comment: Check out the following on why not to use List<T>.ForEach call:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a really **ugly** way to do this. It is **purely academic**.

```
IEnumerable<Thing> things = originals.Select(origo => {DoTell(); return new Thing(origo)});
```

You will update your table and return `new Thing` in `Select`. Select won't fail because you are using brackets in it and tell that you are returning only `new Thing` not result of `DoTell()`

I suggest you to go with `foreach` because it will really look cleaner in the end. Using LINQ everywhere is not a solution for cleaner/clearer code.

EDIT:

if you still want to go with LINQ, you can do even uglier version of it (one-liner):

```
var things = things.Select(x => new { o = new Thing(), b = DoTell()}).Select(x=>x.o);
```

This approach is **pure evil**. However it works without return statement :)

Comment: I agree. LINQ does beautify code, but only when it is necessary

Comment: Oh, that one nice code equilibristics there. Now, you **did** answer the question. However, what if we introduce additional requirement that the telling mustn't be carried out prior the creation of the *Thing*? We can of course store the thingy, do-tell and then return. But I wonder if there's a way to approach it without the *return* statement. (Huge +1 in any case for the creativity.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten As I said, `purely academic` :) I think linq here is not an option. `Language INtegrated Query` means it's for querying rather than looping or modifying data. Nevertheless it's question opens a discussion if there is a need for some extensions to write LINQ-like code for lopping/modifying data.

Comment: @KonradViltersten did it linq style without return.

Comment: @wudzik this answer is the best here, +1

Answer (score 2):

This shall work, using original Select Syntax

```
IEnumerable<Thing> things = originals.Select(origo => 
                                                    {
                                                       DoTell();
                                                       return new Thing(origo);
                                                     });
```

In case `DoTell()` needs to be a post call and it needs to use the `new Thing` created for some internal usage, which is not apparent in this code, then do the following:

```
IEnumerable<Thing> things = originals.Select(origo => 
                                                        {
                                                           var thing = new Thing(origo);
                                                           DoTell();
                                                           return thing;
                                                         });
```

Comment: The user @wudzik beat you to it but still +1 for the reply. Please view my comment to his answer. Is there any way to avoid *return* and still achieve the result? (At this point, the question's been answered. I'm just extra curious.)

Comment: Thanks, I know I am bit slow in replying, but without return in same Select call, chances are less, nonetheless let me check for an alternative

Comment: @KonradViltersten just thinking aloud, if you can call the DoTell from the Thing class constructor being called, then the original concise code itself will work, but that may not be a very good programming practice though. Otherwise you may want to consider an extension method

Answer (score 1):

```
originals.ToList().ForEach(x=>{things.Add(new Thing(x));DoTell();});
```

Comment: `List.ForEach` is not from Linq

Comment: This looks nice. But it's still adding the elements one-by-one. I was thinking less in the lines of do-this-and-that. Rather, I'm looking for select-this-and-do-that. Nevertheless, still a nice syntax, so +1.

Comment: In fact List<T>.ForEach is not a suggested call, check Eric Lippert's link on the same

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I can't see which link you're referring to.

Comment: @KonradViltersten commented on the question, re-pasting the link Eric Lippert:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
originals.ForEach(q =>
{
   //do first thing
   //do second thing 
});
```

Comment: As I commented at the other post - I'd prefer select-do rather than do-do. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Additional explanation ForEach return type is void however Select has return type IEnumerable.
So usage of both depend on context.